# How do you use colons with abbreviations?

Tags: word-usage, colons

If you are writing a report and have to mention the room number, is it correct to write 
Room No.:625, 
Room No. 625, or
Room No: 625
The first example just looks wrong to me, whereas the second and third look fine.  Is there a rule for colons after abbreviations with periods?

Comment: Do you really need the "No" in there? What's wrong with "Room 625"?

Answer (score 1):

The abbr. *no.*, is derived from

> Latin numero, the ablative form of numerus ("number", with the ablative denotations of: "by the number, with the number").
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign))

So, in such a case as is given by the questioner, you should always include either an 'N' with a superscript 'o' or a full stop to show that there has been an abbreviation.

Furthermore, a [search on Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=No.%20%2C%20No.%20%3A%2C%20No%20%3A&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNo.%3B%2Cc0) returns **no** results for the phrases with colons in. 
Finally as a personal touch, I would go for

> Room No. 625

Because it looks far more natural and is commonly used compared to the others (Ngrams)

Comment: The whole ablative thing is how numero would directly translate: Room with the number 625